# TYPO3 Understanding BE Layout + Template

Tags: typo3

I am new to TYPO3 and tried out a little bit so far. Now I am stucked or lets say unsure if it's the right way how I would do it.

First I created a simple HTML file and put some CSS to it. When this simple site was finished, I tried a transition to TYPO3 and created some templates + typoscript code. Now I want to work on the content, so I can create this with the integrated editor in TYPO3 and remove it from my templates.

My site would look like this:

```
Header
News Row (4 Columns)
Another Content Row (3 Columns)
Another Content Row (3 Columns)
Footer
```

Header and Footer are in partials and don't get any content from the editor. For the news section I would use a plugin. The other content rows have to be filled with content from the TYPO3 editor so my first thoughts are that my backend layout must look like this:

```
News Row (do I need 4 columns here or just one and let the plugin work?)
left1 center1 right1
left2 center2 right2
```

Would the backend layout look like this? And for the implementation with typoscript do I have to write all columns in variables e.g. `center < styles.content.get...` and create all elements in the columns there or can I outsource every variable in one file for example?

Hope you guys understand my problem and can give me some good hints!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the news row, use just one column and then modify the [EXT:news](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/news/) templates to arrange the list of news on four columns;

About the other two rows, you have several options, I think

1) each "cell" is defined in your backend layout, and then yes, you would need a separate colPos for each, something like (in TypoScript):

```
center < styles.content.get
left < styles.content.get
left.select.where = colPos = 1
```

2) Same as 1) but you can use the interesting approach used by Benjamin Kott on his [sitepackagebuilder](https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/) . To make it short, he defines a "dynamicContent" TypoScript object that can accept as parameters the colPos and even the id of a specific page. You just write in yout Fluid Template:

```
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.dynamicContent" data="{colPos: '0'}" />
```

And so forth for the others. If you want to discover more, visit https://www.sitepackagebuilder.com/ and create a package (that you could use as a base for your development or just "pillage" it ;) ) You will also find several videos on this topic on the [Youtube TYPO3 official channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/typo3)

3) same as 1) but using the [EXT:vhs](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/vhs/) that adds a specific viewhelper to render the content of a colPos:

```
<v:content.render column="0" />
```

4) Last but not the least you can use [EXT:gridelements](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/gridelements/) to build content element that can have other content elements as children with a "backend_layout" approach. In this approach you just need *one* "cell" in your backend layout, and in this cell you will put a "gridelement" CE that is sub-divided into three separate columns and in each one you can put one or more content elements (same for the third row). This approach will give you the maximum flexibility

I hope I made myself clear, if I misunderstood your question, don't hesitate to write :)

Comment: Thanks, I think I will go with no1 and try 4) later ;)